# Stephan Brandt's habilitation thesis

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I am searching for a copy of Stephan Brandt's habilitation thesis, *Dense graphs with bounded clique number*.  Brandt's thesis is from Freie Universität Berlin in 2001.

I've done what I can to track the thesis down.  I have tried without success to contact Brandt (he has apparently left academia).  An interlibrary loan request came up empty.  In fact, I contacted the library at FU Berlin myself, and I learned that the thesis is missing from the university library.  Finally, I have contacted at least one author of all of the papers that I know of that cite Brandt's thesis, but none of them have been able to give me a copy.

I am grateful for any assistance.

Comment: [dblp](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/hd/b/Brandt:Stephan) shows several recent publications, why do you think he left academia?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Two of Brandt's colleagues told me so.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Martin Aigner? He may have it on his shelf...

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/kseminar/clanky/Elsholtz-multidim_zero_sums.pdf) is not the Habilitationsschrift, but maybe it helps.

[Here](https://www.uni-ulm.de/mawi/mawi-or/mitarbeiter/ehemalige/pd-dr-stephan-brandt.html) is also a contact address from 2013

Comment: apparently, as mentioned [here](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/papers/denseNoClique.pdf), the Habilitationsschrift contains many goodies that are not in the published papers; too bad all academic contact addresses for Dr. Brandt have been disabled